# Unable to use a dynamic string value as the column name when writing to excel

Tags: java, excel

I am attempting to write the value "articlevalue" to an excel sheet. 
I have columns "Monday", "Tuesday" .... "Sunday" in excel as i run it daily.
I work out which column to write the value too, with a string variable called "dayofweek" , but the :

datatable.setCellData("Records",dayofweek,i+1,articlevalue);

It doesn't like the dayofweek variable ?

If i use :
datatable.setCellData("Records","Monday",i+1,articlevalue);

it will work fine, but with i want control over the column value.

See code :

```
  String articlevalue = "1 " + outArray[0] + "\r\n" + "2 " + outArray[1] + "\r\n" + "3 " + outArray[2] + "\r\n" + "4 " + outArray[3] + "\r\n" + "5 " + outArray[4];
//  System.out.println(article value);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK); 

    String todayDate = String.valueOf(day);

        if (todayDate .equals("1")) {
            String dayofweek = "Sunday";
            System.out.println(dayofweek);
        }
        else if (todayDate .equals("2")) {
            String dayofweek = "Monday";
            System.out.println(dayofweek);
        }
        else if (todayDate .equals("3")) {
            String dayofweek = "Tuesday";
            System.out.println(dayofweek);
        }
        else if (todayDate .equals("4")) {
            String dayofweek = "Wednesday";
            System.out.println(dayofweek);
        }
        else if (todayDate .equals("5")) {
            String dayofweek = "Thursday";
            System.out.println(dayofweek);
        }
        else if (todayDate .equals("6")) {
            String dayofweek = "Friday";
            System.out.println(dayofweek);
        }
        else if (todayDate .equals("7")) {
            String dayofweek = "Saturday";
            System.out.println(dayofweek);
        }
// I want to use the following to , but it doesn't like dayofweek
  datatable.setCellData("Records",dayofweek,i+1,articlevalue);
```

Comment: What is `datatable`'s type?

Comment: Xls_Reader datatable = new Xls_Reader("C:\\Temp\\results.xlsx");

Integer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that dayofweek is not defined in the correct scope, so the variable doesn't exist when you do the setCellData call.

Try something like this:

```
    String dayofweek = null;
    if (todayDate .equals("1")) {
        dayofweek = "Sunday";
        System.out.println(dayofweek);
    }
    else if (todayDate .equals("2")) {
        dayofweek = "Monday";
        System.out.println(dayofweek);
    }
    else if (todayDate .equals("3")) {
        dayofweek = "Tuesday";
        System.out.println(dayofweek);
    }
    else if (todayDate .equals("4")) {
        dayofweek = "Wednesday";
        System.out.println(dayofweek);
    }
    else if (todayDate .equals("5")) {
        dayofweek = "Thursday";
        System.out.println(dayofweek);
    }
    else if (todayDate .equals("6")) {
        dayofweek = "Friday";
        System.out.println(dayofweek);
    }
    else if (todayDate .equals("7")) {
        dayofweek = "Saturday";
        System.out.println(dayofweek);
    }
```

This could also be made more elegant by using switch/case, or possibly a Map.